Excel getting names from biggest values with Regextract
I have a small problem with my Excel project and I can't find way how to make it true.
Current formula:
=INDEX(A2:A51; MATCH(LARGE(Value(Iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(split(C2:C51; "-"); "[0-9]+"))); 1) C2:C51; 0))

I want to get names from A column, but I want get the 3 biggest numbers, for example 7 or 13 from C column. If it is text, I want to get 0.

Changes many codes and still get errors.
edit:
this is demo
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vCvMjs28adVSmy80p4BqHokr_PUMxDupalSfLwXGhMk/edit?gid=2100307022#gid=2100307022

Welcome to StackOverFlow! Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Is this an Excel problem, as you write in your question, or a Sheets problem, as per your tags?

Which numbers are you concerned? Numbers between the parentheses or outside?

@Alma_Matters created its very simple

You can try this formula:
=LET(x; SORT(FILTER(A2:F7;C2:C7 <> "No Progress");3;TRUE); y; BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(x;3); LAMBDA(r;SPLIT(r;" "))); CHOOSECOLS(CHOOSEROWS(SORT(HSTACK(x;y);8;FALSE);{1;2;3});{1;3}))

Sample Output:

Reference:
Filter
Sort

When i get home i tried it but i want make more than just 3 dates this was reason why i count data from progress

Kindly leave a comment if you have any clarifications or modifications regarding your expected outcome.

okay its works thanks
